# MySQL: group on timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have a messages table like this:

[image]

And I want to group the messages with the same timestamp into a secondary table. The expected output is something like this:

[image]

I'm using the following script, but for some reason it isn't working:

```
<?php 
$message = mysql_query("select * from message group by member_id");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($message)) {
    @mysql_query("insert into message2 
                 values
                ('$row[time_recorded]','$row[member_id]',
                 '$row[message]')");
}
```

Comment: **Its does not work** Not very useful as error as error messages go. Got a real error message?

Comment: You're suppressing errors with the `@` symbol. Not a very good idea.

Comment: And `GROUP BY` is not going to get you the data you want so that need to be refactored. Take a look at `GROUP_CONCAT()` instead

Comment: What is the point of the 2nd table? You can always run a query that produces the output. If you have it in a table, then the message field length may truncate the messages.

Comment: It's always a good (or mandatory) thing to post what is the outcome of your code. `it doesn't work` is insufficient and prevents us from helping you. Please take this into account whenever you post a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `select *, GROUP_CONCAT(message SEPARATOR ', ') AS message from message group by member_id` in your first selection.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is, that you did not access your array properly. You should access it with an index or Strings (assiciative):

...

```
("insert into message2 values ('"+$row["time_recorded"]+"'"+",'"+$row["member_id"]+"'"+",'"+$row["message"]+"')");
```

...

(notive the " " fieldnames are surrounded with)